# Getting data from an object type in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have stored a class object in Object type on the server side which I am sending to the client. How do I retrieve data of the data members of the class object from the Object type on the client side? I am using WCF for communication. I am new to this concept.

```
Service Contract

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IRCommService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    result sendMessage(string command, object data);
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class result
  {
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> results { get; set; }
  }


[service behavior]
 public result sendMessage(string command, object data)
    {
      List<string> l = new List<string>();
      Console.WriteLine("Received");
      return new result { results = l };
    }
```

Comment: Need more information, is it returned as XML or JSON to the client? Post all of your code that you have so far, it will help greatly with someone offering a solution to your issue.

Comment: I have a simple class with a data member int a. I am making this class's object(with a=10). I want to send this class object to the client side and get this value 10. I am copying the class object into an Object type. Please suggest me how can I do this if this is not the correct way.

Comment: There are walk-throughs which show you how to create both WCF servers and clients at a "hello world" level. Bear in mind that a WCF server can use any of a variety of transports - named pipe, tcp, or http, and can be hosted in a windows service or IIS. How you implement the client depends on which style of hosting and which transport you chose on the server side. If you added a WCF service to an IIS website, you added serviceMetadata to the serviceBehaviors, and the service is running, you can build the client side access by simply adding a service reference in your .NET client project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use Custom request object instead of using Object data type.That request object class should be in common for both of client and sever.then within the client side you can just fill the request and retrieve the required results from the server.

your solution hierarchy is better to be as follows.

[image]

```
namespace ServerProj
{
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using Common;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRCommService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Result SendMessage(string command, CustomRequest data);
    }
}

namespace ServerProj
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Common;

    public class RCommService : IRCommService
    {
        public Result SendMessage(string command, CustomRequest data)
        {   // You can get the value from here
            int value = data.MyValue;

            Result result = new Result();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Sample");
            result.Rsults = list;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Request class in Common assembly

```
namespace Common
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class CustomRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int MyValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Response class in Common assembly

```
namespace Common
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class Result
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> Rsults { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then just add as a service reference in client side.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.RCommServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.RCommServiceClient();
            CustomRequest customRequest=new CustomRequest();
            customRequest.MyValue = 10;

            Result result = service.SendMessage("Test", customRequest);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a Dictionary if you really need that much flexibility.  That being said, it's probably better to have 10 service methods with different signatures than to handle 10 different inputs in one service method.

Also, it's common practice to pass custom classes.  So, if your object has 10 different things, just make a class with 10 properties and set whichever ones you need.